# pandas read_csv() error i.e. FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '19.csv'

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, numpy, csv

I have successfully used the piece of code below in another module to append a column of data to several csv files in a folder:

```
file_path = "%s.csv" % (i)
df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
sma_padded = np.concatenate([np.zeros(len(df) - sma.shape[0]), sma])
df['SMA'] = pd.Series(sma_padded, index=df.index)   
df.to_csv(file_path, index=False)
```

However, in the module I am currently working on when I use the code, I get the error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\Desktop\Algos\TradeBot_BasePlate\indicator_BollingerBands.py", line 85, in <module>
    df = pd.read_csv(file_path)
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "C:\Users\Roy.LAPTOP-1TUG3O1G\AppData\Roaming\Python\Python37\site-packages\pandas\io\parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas\_libs\parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '19.csv'
```

There is no file '19.csv' in the source folder where the csv files are held neither is such a file required by the code in the module.

Comment: So if you do not have the file, why then are you trying to read it in?

Comment: In `file_path = "%s.csv" % (i)`, what is `i`? If this section of code is in a loop and `i` is the index, you need to see why 19 is in that loop. If it's not in a loop, you may have defined `i` in previous loop and `i` will still have the last value from this loop.

Comment: Thank you Tyberius - the "i" had been defined in a another section of the function. I've corrected it and it works perfectly.